# Get-WmiObject -Class powershell command not working in Windows7

Tags: java, swing, powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I have java swing Application where we connect to remote host(ip).
I am using WMI to get OS details of remote host(IP).

When my setup runs on Windows2008R2 ,remote host(IP) get connected .

But the same setup when run on Windows7 , gives me Exception "Access Denied".

I used Powershell to run the Command ..there also i got same  exception

> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername IP -Namespace root\CIMv2 | Format-List -property [a-z]*"

I am logged in as Administrator.

Exception

> [Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESS, DENIED)),

Any idea on this..

Comment: Are you using the same domain user account on both systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command "wmimgmt.msc" from the command line of the computer that is creating the access denied error.  Under "WMI Control" click properties and then the Security tab.  Verify the necessary accounts and groups have the necessary permissions.

[A link to the Microsoft Technet article.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771551.aspx)